# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: android, runtime, build.gradle

I started learning android and trying to call a WebService. The basic code without WebService call was running fine.

Then I added two files to libraries
android-support-v4.jar and android-async-http-1.4.4.jar.

I am receiving the below error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/util/MapCollections$ArrayIterator.class

Below is the part of code is this is required

```
 public void invokeWS(RequestParams params) {
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/OnlineStore/kmsg/grocery/Login";
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.post(url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String response){
                try{
                    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(response);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are logged in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                catch(JSONException jexec){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    jexec.printStackTrace();
                }
            } // End of onSuccess
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int Status, Throwable error, String content){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You failed to login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } // End of onFailure
         }
        ); // End of post function
```

Below is my build.gradle
apply plugin: `'com.android.application'`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "kmsg.com.listwithadapters"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
}
```

From the error it is evident that there is some duplicate entry, but why can't the build system resolve it on its own? Any quick insights will help me understand the reason for this error.

Thanks friends

Comment: minifyEnabled false => true.And do you need multiDexEnabled true?

Comment: minifyEnabled true has not solved the issue. Another point is, when I build only, it is successful. Error occurs only when I run it. But the error says, BUILD ERROR. Bit strange!

Comment: What about remove compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')?

Comment: compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])  has included compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar').

Comment: @tinysunlight the result is same. Still getting the same error. com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/util/MapCollections$ArrayIterator.class

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned it was more of a run time error and the error message which suggested some duplicate entry for class android/support/v4/util/MapCollections$ArrayIterator.class.

I removed the android-support-v4.jar file from libs folder (assuming this is getting duplicated and the error was resolved).

Thanks for all your thoughts and answers though!